# Within VBox guest cheese does not show video, even if it apparantly sees camera

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, video, camera, pop-os

I am running Pop_OS, an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS based distro, on the physical machine. My webcam works, Cheese shows the video, videoconferencing works like a charm.

Besides I have Virtual Box 6.1 guest Pop_OS / Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as guest. When I start cheese it "cannot find a camera". So far so good. Unfortunately when I attach camera to the guest using USB / VBox redirection Cheese starts, finds camera but show no video.

How to make camera work within guest machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this thread:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=87398

I needed to enable "USB 3" in VirtualBox even though the camera is plain old USB1 device.

Now videoconferencing works as expected.

Also this guide:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/webcam-passthrough.html

is worth noting, although I did not try the described method.